# Are polygons with 3 verticles acceptable for a good topology?

Tags: modeling, topology, retopology

In these days I'm working on a model with complex forms so I'm trying to create a good topology. I'm begginer about this technique so I have watched lots of videos on YT which speak about that. Someone says triangular polygons are not good and others say that they are acceptable. So the question is: I must have polygons with 4 verticles or i can also have 3 verticles?

Model reference:
[image]

Comment: If it doesn't create any bad artefacts or bad shading it's ok to use tris

Comment: I would even extend moonboots comment : if it doesn't create any bad artifacts or bad shading, it's ok to use ngons too.

Comment: In general you can say, the need to always use quads is a myth. Some tools like _Loop Cut_ require quads to work, or might give better results with quads like the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier, but it's absolute nonsense to never use tris or ngons.

Comment: .. one thing, though, unless there are reasons not to, I would be tempted to use the triangle that occurs naturally in a UV sphere